# How set Meta data key in php for Rackspace Cloud API

Tags: php, file-upload, cloud, rackspace

I am using Cloud File API of Rackspace Cloud server in PHP, I want to generate a temp url to download files for direct to my server for this i am using `get_temp()` method of this api but before use to this method i have to set Meta Data key for my container. How would i do this.

```
 public function get_temp_url($key, $expires, $method)
{

    $expires += time();
    $url = $this->container->cfs_http->getStorageUrl() .  '/' . $this->container->name . '/' . $this->name;
    return $url . '?temp_url_sig=' . hash_hmac('sha1', strtoupper($method) .
           "\n" . $expires . "\n" . parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH), $key) .
           '&temp_url_expires=' . $expires;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The comments on this page include an example of how to set this:

http://docs.rackspace.com/files/api/v1/cf-devguide/content/Set_Account_Metadata-d1a4460.html

Also, if you use the new Cloud Files API...

https://github.com/rackspace/php-opencloud

...it includes a SetTempUrlSecret method in the ObjectStore class that will do this for you.